# How to redirect with $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect my user to Dashboard after Third Party Login. But when success callback is fired, the application still on Login Page, nothing happened. If I refresh the browser my interceptor catch already login and change to Dashboard... My Login Controller looks like this:

```
ThirdParty.login(function(result){
callbackSUCCESS(result);
},function(){});


function callbackSUCCESS(result){
          AuthenticationService.login(result).then(
                            callbackServerSUCCESS(), function(reject) {
                                callbackServerERROR(reject);
                            });

    }
function callbackServerSUCCESS() {

                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $state.go('dashboard');
                });
            }
```

My route in app.js

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
```

My Header Controller

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', 'AuthenticationService', '$state',
        function($scope, AuthenticationService, $state) {

            $scope.logout = function() {
                AuthenticationService.logout().then(callbackServer(), callbackServer());
            };

            function callbackServer() {
                $state.go('login');
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Authentication Controller Angular Factory

```
 var headersConfig = {   
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
 };

 return {
     login: function(credentials) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();

         $http.post('/api/users/sign_in', sanitizeCredentials(credentials), {
             headers: headersConfig,
             timeout: deferred.promise
         }).then(function(result) {
             if (result.status === 200) {
                 UserSessionService.cacheSession(result.data);
                 deferred.resolve();
             } else {
                 deferred.reject();
             }
         }, function(reject) {
             UserSessionService.clean();
             deferred.reject(reject);
         });

         $timeout(function() {
             deferred.resolve();
         }, 15000);

         return deferred.promise;
     }
 };
```

Comment: My thirdparty eg. github. The flux: login page ->git auth-> my server login -> dashboard

Comment: If you type url into address line do you see your dashboard page?

Comment: No, when I reload the page, then change to http://localhost:9000/dashboard

Comment: I don't think you want the `()` in `then(callbackServer(), callbackServer())`

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the exact semantics of `$state.go`, but usually you need to use `$scope.$apply` in some manner when responding to events Angular isn't aware of, to ensure a digest cycle occurs. I.e. you could try:

```
ThirdParty.login(function(result) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $state.go('dashboard');
    });
}, function() {});
```

You need to get a reference to a scope from somewhere, but one shouldn't be hard to find in an Angular app.

Comment: I got a reference to a scope, but not happened. And console throw:
$apply already in progress

Comment: Do you mean you tried this code and it didn't work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: In sign in nothing happened, so I reload de page to login, then I tried logout and console throw:
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12)
    at beginPhase (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13009:15)

Comment: I have no idea what you have in your logout logic so it's hard to say what's causing that.

Comment: I edit the question to add logout, but in login still didn`t work. Can third dependencies block the flow?

Comment: Now it looks like your AuthenticationService might be an Angular-aware service, since you're getting it via the injector and it supports Angular-style promises. Please edit your post and explain what AuthenticationService is and where you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of both `()` in

```
then(callbackServer(), callbackServer())
```